# Eager loading with constraints generates too many queries. How can I alleviate that?

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have 4 tables that are related in the database and in models as follows:

```
Users (hasMany(communities), hasMany(comments), hasMany(submissions))
Communities (belongsTo(user), hasMany(submissions))
Submissions (belongsTo(community), belongsTo(user), hasMany(comments))
Comments (belongsTo(user) , belongsTo(submission))
```

Now. If I use the relations to get, say the 25 latest submissions, like this:

```
$submissions = Submission::simplePaginate(25);
```

I'm met with 76 queries run, after using foreach to loop through the results.

If I use eager loading with the following

```
$submissions = Submission::with(['user', 'community', 'comments'])->simplePaginate(25);
```

I'm met with 4 queries which is optimal (I think).

Now, my problem is that, on communities, I have a database field called active which accepts a 1 for an active community, and a 0 for an inactive. As you might have guessed, the previous query returns everything, including inactive communities.

I thought about eager loading constraints, so I used the following:

```
$submissions = Submission::with([
      'community' => function($query) {
        $query->active();
      }
    ]  
  )->with(['user', 'comments'])->simplePaginate(25);
```

This still does that job with 4 queries, but now I run into another problem. This method filters the inactive communities, but still loads the posts, users and comments. And now I'm left with a result where I get posts from inactive communities.

Finally, I tried, upon reading this community, the following:

```
   $submissions = Submission::whereHas(
    'community', function($query) {
      $query->active();
    }  
  )->with(['user', 'comments'])->simplePaginate(20);
```

So, instead of using ->with() I used ->whereHas() as someone suggested. However, while this produces the correct results, i.e. it gives me posts, comments and users from the active communities only, it now does that in 23 queries, as per the feedback I get from Laravel Debugbar.

Is this normal? Is this the only way I can do this through Eloquent and without writing custom queries with joins? Am I blowing 23 queries out of proportion?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You said you replaced `->with()` with `->whereHas()` but the code you posed uses both...you still geting 23 queries?

Comment: Your problem is that the `active()` scope is running a query for every community you get.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `active()` scope is running a query for every community you are retrieving, in your case 20.

To optimize this you could make a specific relation in the `Submission` model where you filter the active communities proactively.

```
// Submission model

public function activeCommunities (){

    return $this->hasMany(Community::class)->whereActive(true); 
}
```

Now your query would look like:

```
$submissions = Submission::with(['user', 'comments', 'activeCommunities])  
    ->simplePaginate(25);
```

This should perform 4 queries I believe.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: While your answer makes sense, upon trying it, it still produces 28 queries. The code I used is the following

for the model, and 


`$submissions = Submission::with(['user', 'filtered'])->withCount('comments')->simplePaginate(25);`

Comment: @GeorgeChatzipavlou If you could edit your post with the queries you are getting it would be very helpful, so I could know where they are coming from. Let me know when you've done it.

Answer (score 0):

So, after tinkering with it for a while, I found a solution, but I'm still not sure. I'm posting this for future reference, since it solved my problem. The code I used is the following

```
  $submissions = Submission::whereHas(
      'community', function($query) {
        $query->where('is_active', true);
      }
    )->with(['user', 'community'])->withCount('comments')
  ->paginate(25);
```

So, I tried using `whereHas()` to check for the models existence before actually eager loading the `community` model, if that makes sense? It seems to get me the results I want, since I now execute a total of 4 queries to get all the submissions, and the related info, filtering the inactive communities.